# framerate independent animation issues

Tags: c++, animation

For whatever reason, my character moves faster going left than right. It's at least twice as fast.

Here is the portion of code that checks the character movement:

```
if(moving)
{
    Uint32 delta = g_delta_get_ticks();
    if(!g_holding_a) 
    {
        position.x += accel * (delta / 1000.f);
        facing = right;
    }
    if(!g_holding_d) 
    {
        position.x -= accel * (delta / 1000.f);
        facing = left;
    }
}
```

Now, my first guess would be the timer is acting funny, but, even placing in static values like `accel * (50 / 1000.f)` results in the same behavior.

Now, If I just tell the positions to be `+= and -= 2`, it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of position.x?

Comment: `struct XY { GLuint x, y; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect truncation is causing your trouble.  When you say `some_int += some_float` (or `some_int -= some_float`), the arithmetic is done in floating-point, then truncated to an integer.  So if `some_int` is 100 and `some_float` is 1.5, then after `some_int += some_float`, you get 101 (truncated from 101.5).  But after `some_int -= some_float`, you get 98 (truncated from 98.5).

Since you're using `GLuint` for `position.x`, try truncating the adjustment into a `GLuint` before adding or subtracting it:

```
GLuint d = accel * (delta / 1000.f);
if (!g_holding_a) {
    position.x += d;
    facing = right;
}
if (!g_holding_d) {
    position.x -= d;
    facing = left;
}
```

Comment: Good call! That seems to have fixed the problem. I had to also reset the time BEFORE swapping the buffers. Which now come to think of it, makes a lot of sense. Thanks!